# Java incorrect bytecode

Tags: java, minecraft, decompiling

I am decompiling Minecraft 1.5.2 code, and in file als.java there is subtraction performed with void method, also void tried to put to int var:

```
/*
 * Decompiled with CFR 0.152.
 */
import java.util.Random;

public class als
extends aly
implements amh {
    public als(int n2, boolean bl2) {
        super(n2, bl2);
        this.cF = true;
    }

    public int a(int n2, Random random, int n3) {
        return wk.bY.cp;
    }

    public int d(aab aab2, int n2, int n3, int n4) {
        return wk.bY.cp;
    }

    protected int i_(int n2) {
        return 2;
    }

    protected aly i() {
        return apa.cq;
    }

    protected aly j() {
        return apa.cp;
    }

    public int d() {
        return 37;
    }

    public lx a(int n2, int n3) {
        boolean bl2;
        boolean bl3 = bl2 = this.a || (n3 & 8) != 0;
        if (n2 == 0) {
            if (bl2) {
                return apa.aU.m(n2);
            }
            return apa.aT.m(n2);
        }
        if (n2 == 1) {
            if (bl2) {
                return apa.cq.cQ;
            }
            return this.cQ;
        }
        return apa.an.m(1);
    }

    protected boolean c(int n2) {
        return this.a || (n2 & 8) != 0;
    }

    protected int d(aak aak2, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5) {
        return this.a_(aak2, n2, n3, n4).a();
    }

    private int m(aab aab2, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5) {
        if (!this.d(n5)) {
            return this.e(aab2, n2, n3, n4, n5);
        }
        return Math.max(this.e(aab2, n2, n3, n4, n5) - this.f((aak)aab2, n2, n3, n4, n5), 0);
    }

    public boolean d(int n2) {
        return (n2 & 4) == 4;
    }

    protected boolean d(aab aab2, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5) {
        int n6 = this.e(aab2, n2, n3, n4, n5);
        if (n6 >= 15) {
            return true;
        }
        if (n6 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        int n7 = this.f((aak)aab2, n2, n3, n4, n5);
        if (n7 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return n6 >= n7;
    }

    protected int e(aab aab2, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5) {
        int n6;
        int n7 = super.e(aab2, n2, n3, n4, n5);
        int n8 = als.j(n5);
        int n9 = n2 + r.a[n8];
        int n10 = aab2.a(n9, n3, n6 = n4 + r.b[n8]);
        if (n10 > 0) {
            if (apa.r[n10].q_()) {
                n7 = apa.r[n10].b_(aab2, n9, n3, n6, r.f[n8]);
            } else if (n7 < 15 && apa.l(n10) && (n10 = aab2.a(n9 += r.a[n8], n3, n6 += r.b[n8])) > 0 && apa.r[n10].q_()) {
                n7 = apa.r[n10].b_(aab2, n9, n3, n6, r.f[n8]);
            }
        }
        return n7;
    }

    public aqa a_(aak aak2, int n2, int n3, int n4) {
        return (aqa)aak2.r(n2, n3, n4);
    }

    public boolean a(aab aab2, int n2, int n3, int n4, sq sq2, int n5, float f2, float f3, float f4) {
        int n6 = aab2.h(n2, n3, n4);
        boolean bl2 = this.a | (n6 & 8) != 0;
        boolean bl3 = !this.d(n6);
        int n7 = bl3 ? 4 : 0;
        aab2.a((double)n2 + 0.5, (double)n3 + 0.5, (double)n4 + 0.5, "random.click", 0.3f, bl3 ? 0.55f : 0.5f);
        aab2.b(n2, n3, n4, (n7 |= bl2 ? 8 : 0) | n6 & 3, 2);
        this.c(aab2, n2, n3, n4, aab2.s);
        return true;
    }

    protected void f(aab aab2, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5) {
        int n6;
        int n7;
        int n8;
        if (!(aab2.a(n2, n3, n4, this.cz) || (n8 = this.m(aab2, n2, n3, n4, n7 = aab2.h(n2, n3, n4))) == (n6 = this.a_(aab2, n2, n3, n4).a()) && this.c(n7) == this.d(aab2, n2, n3, n4, n7))) {
            if (this.h(aab2, n2, n3, n4, n7)) {
                aab2.a(n2, n3, n4, this.cz, this.i_(0), -1);
            } else {
                aab2.a(n2, n3, n4, this.cz, this.i_(0), 0);
            }
        }
    }

    private void c(aab aab2, int n2, int n3, int n4, Random random) {
        int n5 = aab2.h(n2, n3, n4);
        int n6 = this.m(aab2, n2, n3, n4, n5);
        int n7 = this.a_(aab2, n2, n3, n4).a();
        this.a_(aab2, n2, n3, n4).a(n6);
        if (n7 != n6 || !this.d(n5)) {
            boolean bl2;
            boolean bl3 = this.d(aab2, n2, n3, n4, n5);
            boolean bl4 = bl2 = this.a || (n5 & 8) != 0;
            if (bl2 && !bl3) {
                aab2.b(n2, n3, n4, n5 & 0xFFFFFFF7, 2);
            } else if (!bl2 && bl3) {
                aab2.b(n2, n3, n4, n5 | 8, 2);
            }
            this.h_(aab2, n2, n3, n4);
        }
    }

    public void a(aab aab2, int n2, int n3, int n4, Random random) {
        if (this.a) {
            int n5 = aab2.h(n2, n3, n4);
            aab2.f(n2, n3, n4, this.j().cz, n5 | 8, 4);
        }
        this.c(aab2, n2, n3, n4, random);
    }

    public void a(aab aab2, int n2, int n3, int n4) {
        super.a(aab2, n2, n3, n4);
        aab2.a(n2, n3, n4, this.b(aab2));
    }

    public void a(aab aab2, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5, int n6) {
        super.a(aab2, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6);
        aab2.s(n2, n3, n4);
        this.h_(aab2, n2, n3, n4);
    }

    public boolean b(aab aab2, int n2, int n3, int n4, int n5, int n6) {
        super.b(aab2, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6);
        aqp aqp2 = aab2.r(n2, n3, n4);
        if (aqp2 != null) {
            return aqp2.b(n5, n6);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void a(ly ly2) {
        this.cQ = ly2.a(this.a ? "comparator_lit" : "comparator");
    }

    public aqp b(aab aab2) {
        return new aqa();
    }
}
```

I also tried it with Fernflower (in IntelliJ IDEA) and with JD-GUI. Results are the same. Why does it happen? The reason why I am decompiling Minecraft is because I want to try to optimize it just for myself.
Maybe I need to change `f` method and return some var declared in it... This is the first class I noted this in, but, I think there are a lot of classes like this one in nearly 1500 files. Thanks for any help.

**UPD:**
I found that in class `aly` (super class) there is protected `int f` method, maybe I need to call it?

**UPD 2:**
Seven months later, I cringe at this stupid question..

Comment: Since `aab2` is cast to `aak` (initially `aab`), it is probable that the `f` method called is not the one we see in `als`

Comment: hmm, didnt noticed it, im currently fixing the code after decompilation, but thanks anyway

Comment: ok, now it looks kinda impossible, because some methods are tried to be called on primitive types.. probably I need to analyze bytecode

Comment: Why are you doing all of this work yourself when it's already been done? There are already MCP mappings for 1.5.2.

Comment: Yeees, I have just wanted to write about this. Already downloaded it and it works. But thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I remembered about a thing called MCP (Minecraft Coder Pack). I downloaded it, then had a little pain with it, but got it working.